# nginx, upstream, cors fail

Tags: node.js, nginx, cors

Can't grasp why my upstream / CORS config is failing.  This is preventing some local dev and testing.

I'm getting a **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource** when making an API request from **local.mysite.com:8081** to **events.mysite.com**.

Here is my server config from /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite

```
# the IP(s) on which your node server is running. I chose port 3000.
upstream mysite {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

# the nginx server instance
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name mysite events.mysite.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.log;

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers and much more can be added, see nginx config options
    location / {
      proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
      # proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';   # i've tried with and without this setting
      proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin';
      proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://app_mysite/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```

**also**, I tried using **add_header** and not proxy_set_header on the Access-Control-* options, but no dice there either.

I'm running a Node.js app.  I have not modified the Node code to handle CORS... is my nginx config wrong, or is it fine but I need to do something else in Node?

Answer (score 1):

CORS headers have to be served to browser, not your node application. So you should use `add_header` directive or, better, set these headers in your application. This should be enough. If you do use `withCredentials` uncomment appropriate line. If you use something that makes browser to send preflight request, you should properly handle 'OPTIONS' request.

```
location / {
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
  # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;

  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

  proxy_pass http://app_mysite/;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Comment: No dice -- I noted above that I had also tried add_header.  I've tried super simple header modifications in my app, but I'm new to Node and must be doing it wrong.  Basically I have this:

`function start(route, handle) {
      function onRequest(request, response) {
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    ...  rest of server.js`

Comment: It looks like on localhost I now get a failed OPTIONS call.  net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: How do you request this url?

Comment: Finally got it -- thank you for responding, and you're right, the change needed to happen in my Node.js code, which still had an issue.  In my function that sets the headers, I changed Allow-Headers to this:  `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");`